# How to prove that the Statistical Entropy $S_{BG}$ is concave

Tags: functional-analysis, convex-analysis, functional-inequalities, statistical-mechanics

So I am for the moment studying the properties of the Boltzmann-Gibbs statistical entropy

\begin{equation}
S_{BG}=-k_B \sum_{i}p_i\ln p_i,
\end{equation}
where of course $k_B$ is the Boltzmann constant. Now, among the properties it is stated that the entropy has an extremum for equal probabilities and then it mentions that $S_{BG}$ is concave, therefore this particular extremum is a maximum.

Now, I can define:
\begin{equation}
p^{''}_i=\lambda p_i+(1-\lambda)p_i^{'}
\end{equation}
for two distinct probability sets $\{ p_i\}$, $\{ p_i^{'} \}$ *(associated with the system states W)* and then use the definition of a concave functional to prove:
\begin{equation}
S_{BG}(\{ p_i^{''}\})>\lambda S_{BG}(\{ p_i^{}\})+(1-\lambda)S_{BG}(\{ p_i^{'}\})
\end{equation}

That's as far as I can get. I cannot prove the concavity inequality. Even though I do know that it has something to do with the one dimension function $f(x)=x\ln (x), x>0$ which is convex, therefore $-f(x)$ will be concave. But that is considered for a real function of 1-dimension.
Anyway, I am sure it's simple but I can't see it.

Any ideas?? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $f(x)$ is concave, then so is $g(x_1, \ldots, x_n) = f(x_1)$.

A sum of concave functions is concave.

Comment: So simple. Yeap. That'll do it. Thanks!